# How to build Android.jar with all hidden internal APIs

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source, android-build

I am trying to build `Android.jar` file (such as [this](https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms/tree/master/android-17)) for `KitKat` version which contains all hidden/internal APIs as well as required `Java` and `Apache` libraries. I do not intend to use these APIs in any Android application but I need this jar file for another analysis purpose.

Should I build Android SDK from its source code or extract some jar files and combine them together?

Comment: What do you mean by hidden/internal APIs?

Comment: Some APIs are hidden with @hide annotation. These APIs by-default are not included in SDK-provided Android.jar file. I want to include these APIs as well.